# Check android device density in html

Tags: android, html, css

How do I check device density of android device inside html page?
I tried below code but not working for android device -

```
if($(window).devicePixelRatio == 1) {
    a1=a1+a1*5;
}
else if($(window).devicePixelRatio == 2) {
    a1=a1+a1*10;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get device density by using javaScriptInterFace.

```
wv.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(context),
            "jsInterface");


public class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public float getDensity() {
        return scale = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    }
}
```

and in your html get density by javascript

```
var scale = jsInterface.getDensity();
```

- 0.75 means low density
- 1.0 means standard (medium) density
- 1.5 means high (large) density
- 2.0 means extra high density